# C# ComboBox AutoComplete Suggestions

Tags: c#

I've read a lot of post, but haven't really found anything to help with this problem. I want to select all cells from a database that contains the current text being type in the combobox.

But when I try it this way it only lets me enter 1 character at a time.

```
private void GetSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var src = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    var tmp = _sqlite.GetDataTable("select customer from Machines");
    foreach (DataRow r in tmp.Rows)
    {
        if (r[0].ToString().Contains(CmbCustomer.Text))
            src.Add(r[0].ToString());
    }

    CmbCustomer.AutoCompleteCustomSource = src;

}
```

Is there a way of doing this? Thank in advance!

Comment: The problem is not in this code snippet.  If it was you'd already have found it.  Try adding a handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event and see how it got triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query to do a LIKE search (e.g. SELECT Customer FROM Machines WHERE Customer LIKE **CmbCustomer.Text + "%"** ).  This will select a narrower result set that matches as many characters as you put in.

Comment: If I'm type in "ole" will that query return "cole, woley, boce-2" ?

Comment: if you want to search anything that CONTAINS a value, you need to put a percent at the start and end.  Example: "LIKE %OLE%"

Answer (score 0):

You should check the string for a match on the SQLite side of things, in your select query. "it only lets me enter 1 character at a time" is too vague to tell you exactly what's wrong, but it might be taking some time to do the search. If that is the case, you can try to only refresh the auto-complete every half second or so, using a timer.

Comment: Say I start to type "cole" I will get the c in the comobox, then it will select the text and set the caret back to the beginning , so when I type the next letter 'o' it erases c and so on.